# Merge the matches from regular expressions into a single list

Tags: python, regex-group

I am trying to separate a string in CamelCase into a single list

I managed to separate the words with regular expressions

But I am clueless on how create a single list of all the matches

I tried to concatenate the lists, append something like that but I don't think it would work in my case

```
n="SafaNeelHelloAByeSafaJasleen"
patt=re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z$])')
matches=patt.finditer(n)
for match in matches:
    a=match.group()
    list=a.split()
    print(list)
```

output:

```
['Safa']

['Neel']

['Hello']

['A']

['Bye']

['Safa']

['Jasleen']
```

Desired output:

```
['Safa','Neel','Hello','A','Bye','Safa','Jasleen']
```

Comment: `patt.findall(n)` returns a list of all the matches...

Comment: `print(list(m.group() for m in matches))`

Comment: The regexp can never match more than one word. Why do you need `a.split()`?

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in class name.

Comment: @Barmar So when I was using re.finditer() the matches came individually, so I thought if i group them split them into individual lists and combine those lists, I would get the desired results. I don't know if this makes sense, but I did try re.findall() earlier, I guess I made some errors but this time it worked. You can definitely guess that I am a beginner here, but I would love to thank all of you for making this platform available so new python learners like me can keep improving.

Comment: @ddejohn Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `re.findall()`, not `re.finditer()`:

```py
>>> string = "SafaNeelHelloAByeSafaJasleen"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z$])")
>>> pattern.findall(string)
['Safa', 'Neel', 'Hello', 'A', 'Bye', 'Safa', 'Jasleen']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the matches to new list:

```
new_list=[]
for match in matches:
    a=match.group()
    new_list.append(a)
```

Output of new_list:

```
['Safa', 'Neel', 'Hello', 'A', 'Bye', 'Safa', 'Jasleen']
```